# How to apply usergroup changes without having to end session / logging out / closing programs?

Tags: users, group, session, privileges

I'd like to remove myself from usergroups via `deluser username group-to-get-removed-from` without having to log out and back in as most programs get closed when doing so. Is there a way to apply usergroup changes via the console without having all the opened applications closed?

I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Comment: Not sure if you can but what you can do is enable a screen session make the changes and dettach the screen session then log out and log back in.. I am not a 100% if that works but that would certainly keep your PIDs running for your user

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply a group membership change to already-running programs. The group database is consulted at login time, and the login process puts itself into all the groups that the user is a member of. After this processes inherit the groups of their parent.

If you want to apply a group membership immediately, log in again, for example with `ssh localhost`. That doesn't work for already-running programs.